# Critique of a proof about a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I am writing a critique of the proof of the following statement:

> The subset $C = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty C_n$, where $$C_n = \{ (x,y) \mid x = \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{and} \quad 0 \leq y \leq \frac{1}{n} \}$$ for all positive integers $n$, is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$

This statement, in my opinion, is not correct. For every neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ intersects $C_n$ for every $n$ but is not contained in any $C_n$. The proof, of which I present only a sketch, makes use of the following idea:

> Take the sets $A_n = \{ (x,y) \mid x < \frac{1}{n}, y < \frac{1}{n} \}$  and the sets $B_n = \{ (x,y) \mid x < \frac{1}{n}, y > \frac{1}{n+1} \}$ which are open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $$ C^{c} = \text{Ext}(A_1) \cup \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty( \text{Int}(A_n) \cup \text{Int}(B_n) )\cap \text{Ext}(A_{n+1})$$ is open because finite union of opens is open and arbritrary unions of opens is again open. As the complement is open, $C$ is closed.

My problem, lies in the fact, that the author has written this in a very convincing manner and, this is my first critique. So I am unsure if I am right. There should be a logical problem with this proof, but I honestly donot see it.

**Edit**: The set $C$ is in fact neither open nor closed. The end point $(1,1)$ has a neighbourhood which is not contained in $C$. If we were to take the union of $C$ with $[0,1]\times \mathbb{R}$ it would be closed.

**Edit**: Oops, Should be $[0,1]\times {0} $

***Edit***: I officially, cannot see how I can fix this proof. I will try again tomorrow. Any help would be highly appreciated, as always. Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: You are right: $(0,0) \notin C$, despite it is a limit point of $C$. So $C$ is not closed. But if you take $C \cup \{ (0,0) \}$, then you get a closed set.

Answer (score 2):

The equation of sets in the box is false; for example, the closed 3rd quadrant (including the point $(0,0)$) is contained in $C^c$ but is disjoint from the right hand side. So this sounds like an exercise in set theory. To get started, the sets $A_n$ and $B_n$ are open, so both equal their own interiors. Also, no matter what the positive integer $n$ is, each real number $y$ satisfies either $y < \frac{1}{n}$ or $y > \frac{1}{n+1}$, possibly both. So, the expression $\text{Int}(A_n) \cup \text{Int}(B_n)$ can be simplified to the set $\{(x,y) \, | \, x < \frac{1}{n}\}$. It shouldn't be too hard to continue from here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the proof strategy would would work if the space included the 1st quadrant including (0,0). Well actually, only the interval $[0,1] \times \{0\}$ should be enough.